# JPATH Base with unix

Tags: php, joomla

Hi I'm wondering if someone can help me here.

I am trying to implement single signon between a joomla site and a PHP app of mine, the app comes with instructions that the JBASE instructions must be set such as:

```
// change the following line to point to your Joomla 3.1 installation
define('JPATH_BASE', "c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla31\\" );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

As you can see this is for a windows IIS setup and I am using linux, I have tried:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', "\home\sites\jkgsoft.com\public_html\rent360" );
```

But then get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(\home\sites\jkgsoft.com\public_html ent360/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 453 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '\home\sites\jkgsoft.com\public_html ent360/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear53:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/ZendFramework') in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 453
```

Does anyone know maybe how to change this JPATH?

Answer (score 0):

You could work with [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). It will give you the root path of your server

```
define('JPATH_BASE',  __DIR__ . "/rent360" );
```

*this is a PHP 5.3 solution*

Comment: rent360 is a subsite to main publichtml site so yes its a subfolder, thanks will give it a try

Comment: No afraid not, get this. Warning: require_once(/home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/rent360/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 462 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/rent360/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear53:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/ZendFramework') in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 462

Comment: Can you give the output of `echo __DIR__;` ?

Comment: /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include

Comment: it is almost right - needs to point to /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/include, and cut out the portal, but will try typing that in manually

Comment: seems to work ok with define('JPATH_BASE', '/home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/' );

Comment: @Simon79 - do not use absolute paths when defining a path

Comment: Thanks, tried it your way define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360')); and get this Warning: require_once(/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 464 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear53:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/ZendFramework') in /home/sites/jkgsoft.com/public_html/rent360/portal/include/appsettings.php on line 464

Comment: @Simon79 - `My way`? I did not write this. Please look at the code I have actually provided and as mentioned before, **do not use absolute paths**.

Comment: I'm a little over my head here, the code you gave was: define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../rent360'));  how would you suggest I use that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `realpath` and `dirname` for this like so:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../rent360'));
```